# Expressjs session not persiting between routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session, cookies

I have scoured the community for answers, but I cant seem to find one.
In my application, I send user info from the client (react) to `/user/save` route. When I log the session to the console, all the data is there. But when I log `req.session` out on any other route it doesn't have any data.
Right now I am accessing the API from localHost while the API is hosted with ngrok.
When I had the API integrated within the same codebase as my React app, all worked well, but now it's a bit funky.

**Server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
var cron = require('node-cron');
require('dotenv').config()

const corsConfig = {
  "origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "credentials": true
};
  // Implemented a rate limiter which is a TEMPORARY FIX for the infinite loop by the useEffect
  const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: .1 * 60 * 1000, // 10 seconds limit
    max: 4 
  });
    // Middleware
  const hostValidationMiddleware = require('./Middleware/HostValidationMiddleware');
  const sessionValidationMiddleware = require('./Middleware/SessionValidationMiddleware');
  const {authenticateJWT} = require('./Middleware/JwtMiddleware');
  
    
    
    async function connectToDB() {  
        // Database 
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.mongo_url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },  () => {
            
            console.log('[connectToDB]: Connected to DB'); 
        })
      }
    connectToDB();
    app.use(cookieParser());

    const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    // Creating the session in order to save user data to req.session
  app.use(
    expressSession({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        secure: false,
        cookie: { 
                maxAge: oneDay,
                sameSite: "none",
               }
      })
    );
app.use(cors(corsConfig)); 
//app.use('/', limiter);
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', hostValidationMiddleware, sessionValidationMiddleware, require('./Routes/Store-Invoices'));
app.use('/', require('./Routes/SaveLoggedInUser') , authenticateJWT, require('./Routes/GetUserInvoices'));
app.use('/', require('./Routes/UpdateUserData'));


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

  app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on 8081`);
  });
```

**Saved Logged In User**

```js
saveLoggedInUser.post('/user/save', async (req, res) => {
  const User =  req.body;
  const token = await GetJwt(User); 
    req.session.currentUser = User;
    if (token && !('authorization' in req.session) && User) {
      req.session.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
      req.session.save();      
    }
    console.log('USER', req.session); 
    const usersFromDB = await fetchUsersFromDB().catch((e) => { console.log(e) });
    findCommonUser(usersFromDB,User);
    res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

**Get User Invoices**

```js
userInvoices.get('/invoice/user', async (req,res) => {
 
  const invoices = await InvoiceModel.find().catch((e) => {console.log(e)});
  const user =   req.session;
  console.log('INVOICE',user);
  });
```

**Client Call**

```js
  async function fetchUserInvoices() {

    // Making a call to external api
    const url = `https://f604-104-49-198-21.ngrok.io/invoice/user`;
    const invoiceResponse = await axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true}).catch((e) => { console.log(e) });
    setData(invoiceResponse.data); 
    return;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your SameSite cookie flag set to "none" which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) now requires the "Secure" flag to also be set to true in order to work. However, as you're using localhost, you probably also can't set Secure to true since you're not on HTTPS.

Removing that line in your Server.js code fixed it for me, as did setting sameSite: "strict".

Comment: That didnt work, it looks like there are 2 cookies being used.